# If statement issue with Var Prompt

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'else'".  Can anyone help me figure as to why this is?

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("I am ready to play!");
var age = prompt("What's your age?");
if(age === 13)
{
console.log("You are allowed to play but at your own risk.");
}
else
{
console.log("Play on!");
}
console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this 
lyric      'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");
if(userAnswer === "yes")
{
console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! 
You win by   a shoelace!");
}
else(userAnswer === "no")
{
console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, 
so I can race without pacing.'");
}
var feedback = prompt("Rate Game 1-10");
if(feedback > 8)
{
console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
else(feedback < 8)
{
console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
```

I keep getting an error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'else'".  Can anyone help me figure as to why this is?

Comment: You're missing a `}` after the `console.log` at `if(feedback > 8)` but also you can't have an unescaped newline in a string,

Comment: Format your code properly. Makes it easier to see syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this bit of code?

```
if(feedback > 8)
{
console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
else(feedback < 8)
{
```

It should be:

```
if(feedback > 8)
{
console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
}
else(feedback < 8)
{
```

You were missing a `}`. Also, note the comment from T.J. `else` doesn't take a condition, so really it should be:

```
if(feedback > 8)
{
console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
}
else
{
```

The following is also problematic if this is how it exists in your code, but I'm going to assume it's a copy/paste issue. You can't split a string like this on to multiple lines unless you escape it.

```
console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this 
lyric      'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
```

Comment: `else` doesn't take a condition. Good catch on the missing brace.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

1. `else` doesn't take a condition, so lines like

   ```
   else(userAnswer === "no")
   ```

   don't do what you think they do, which leads to syntax errors later on. Instead:

   ```
   else if (userAnswer === "no")
   ```
2. You can't just put a line break in the middle of a string literal like that, not with strings quoted with `"` or `'`. (You can with ES6's new template strings quoted with ```, but support is thin on the ground so far.)
3. Indentation is your friend. Use it. http://jsbeautifier.org or any half-decent IDE can help.

...and see [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32628735/157247) about a missing `}`, which would be more obvious if you used indentation (#3 above).

Answer (score 0):

There is closing } missing in your js

```
if(feedback > 8)
{
console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
else(feedback < 8)
{
console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
```

**Corrected Code**

```
if(feedback > 8)
{
console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
}
else(feedback < 8)
{
console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
```